# Send git revision of file by mail

Tags: tortoise-git

I use git repositories for various documents and TortoiseGit to handle them.

Sometimes, I have to send a document to somebody else for revision, or if (s)he requests an older version of it.

I can do that by...

1. Opening the Tortoise git log of the directory.
2. (If needed) Select the commit.
3. Right-click the file.
4. Select "Save revision to".
5. Save the file somewhere.
6. Use my mail program to attach it to an email.
7. Remove the exported file.

I am annoyed by steps 4./5., and I always forget step 7. -- is there any way to add something like "Send revision by mail" into the menu?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2545784/1054225 ?

Comment: No no, not the entire repository, I just want a single revision of one single file in the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite easy, this small .bat file can do it:

```
...
PAUSE
```

The `...` has to be replaced with the mail program (e.g. `C:\Program Files\MyCoolMailProgram\program.exe /newMail /attachment %~1`), the file to attach is in `%1` (or `%~1` to remove the `"`s).

In TortoiseGit, you can then choose *Open with...* and the script. TortoiseGit creates the file revision as a temporary file somewhere and gives the temporary file's path to your script (`%1`), et voila. :-)

The `PAUSE` at the end of the script makes sure that the script is open until you press a key inside the cmd window -- I do not know, when TortoiseGit removes the temporary file, so we keep the script open.